# Github Pages and Jekyll Do Not Match

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I just created github pages using Jekyll, but between `_config.yml` and my github page it doesn't match. Where is my mistake?

Actually there are some errors (not match), but as an example please see the titles from both places. From `_config.yml` i've made "ABAYblablabla | Indonesian Developer Wannabe" as title. But on github instead it raises "About Me". Can someone help me adjust between GitHub Pages and the Source Code?

Config https://github.com/abaykan/abaykan.github.io/blob/master/_config.yml

Github Pages https://abaykan.github.io/

> Sorry, i'm using google translate. My English is messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `title: my page title` in your **index.md** front matter, and Github Pages is guessing one from html headers. When it finds `<h1>About Me</h1>` it sets **index.md** title to "About Me".

You then have **_layout/default.html** that sets page title like this :

```
{% if page.title %}{{ page.title }}{% else %}{{ site.title }}{% endif %}
```

That means that it prints `page.title` OR `site.title`, NOT both.

If you want to print `site.title` AND eventually `page.title`, you can do :

```
{{ site.title }}{% if page.title %} - {{ page.title }}{% endif %}
```

Comment: I also try to edit some css (when i run in local), but when i run `jekyll serve` the css back as before

Comment: Maybe because you're editing css in **_site** directory, which is the generated site. If you want to edit, it's in **css** ans **_sass** folder only.